# CV% with Close-End Formula

Tags: bioinformatics, coefficient-of-variation

I am working with qPCR data, where the quantity of genetic material (in picograms) is the direct output of the machine. The quantity is then entered into a close end formula, which accounts for dilutions and conversion from pg to direct viral copies, to derive the number of viral copies/mL.

The quantities (direct output from the qPCR instrument) are around 2.5-3.5x10^-3 pg. The closed-end formula is as follows: (X*50,000*7.56791x10^6)/(20*1x10^-3), where X is the quantity of the genetic material in pg. The number of copies/mL after "transformation" are ~2.2-3.0x10^11).

I have been tasked with summarizing the variability of this analysis. I originally summarized the variability using the genetic quantity and then plugged those values into the closed-end formula to "transform" into copies/mL, so the variability is more easily interpretable.

I just recently learned that our test method requires the reporting of the average of the copies/mL rather than the average genomic quantity. I am trying to figure out whether the two methods of calculating CV% are the same. Given that the data should maintain the same distance when "moved up" the number line, I don't think there should be any issues. However, I just want to make sure that I am not missing anything.

Here is how I had calculated CV%:

St. Dev. of Quantity/Arithmetic Mean of Quantity * 100

Here is how the lab analyst calculated CV%:

Quantity plugged into close end formula --> copies/mL

St. Dev. of Copies/mL/Arithmetic Mean of Copies/mL * 100

Please feel free to comment any additional questions. Thanks!

Answered my own question. Got the same CV% when I calculate different ways: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0WTK.png

Comment: What does "X" represent?  What is a "closed-end" formula?  What exactly are you trying to compute? ("CV%" and "copies per mL" sound entirely different.)  What point are you trying to make about "should maintain the same distance"?

Comment: Solved it myself. Added an image of the output to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: CV% by different methods]

CV%s were the same by both methods when I recalculated.

**R Code**

*Original Method*

```
qpcr_raw_analysis <- qpcr_raw %>%
  group_by(test_name_numeric, concentration_ordinal) %>%
  summarise(
    count = n(),
    mean = mean(quantity),
    median = median(quantity),
    std = sd(quantity),
    cv = (std/mean)*100,
    iqr = iqr(quantity), 
    min = min(quantity),
    max = max(quantity), 
    .groups = "keep"
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

*Analyst method*

```
qpcr_copies_analysis <- qpcr_copies %>%
  group_by(test_name_numeric, concentration_ordinal) %>%
  summarise(
    count = n(),
    mean = mean(copies),
    median = median(copies),
    std = sd(copies),
    cv = (std/mean)*100,
    iqr = iqr(copies), 
    min = min(copies),
    max = max(copies), 
    .groups = "keep"
  )
```